# is_base_of of generic type

Tags: c++, templates, generics, type-traits

I'm trying to assert that template parameter would be derived from some base class. But base class is generic and in the context of assertion there is no difference between any specialization types. 
How can I assert, that template parameter were derived from generic of any specialized type?

I'm trying to write it as

base_generic:

```
template<typename T> struct base_generic{};
```

derived_generic:

```
template<typename T> struct derived_generic : public base_generic<T>{};
```

class with assertion:

```
template<typename Tsource, typename Tderived_generic> 
struct encoder {
static_assert(std::is_base_of<base_generic<typename>, Tderived_generic>::value);
};
```

This code compiles, but assertion fails

Comment: You mean something like `template <typename> struct base_generic{}; struct derived_generic: base_generic<int> {};`?

Comment: Please post declarations for `base_generic` and `derived_generic`.

Comment: Give a minimal but complete sample what you're actually doing please.

Comment: This question isn't bad, but lacks of research/trying effort and a mcve.

Comment: template<typename T> struct base_generic{};

template<typename T struct derived_generic : public base_generic<T> {};

Comment: Can you show the call of the assertion that fails?

Comment: There are 
template<typename Tsource, typename Tstorage> struct {};
that second template parameter should be derived from base_generic

Comment: assertion is static_assert(std::is_base_of<base_generic<typename>, derived_generic>::value,
    "Storage should be derived from base_generic");

Comment: @SemyonBurov  Add additional information [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32477691/edit) please.

Comment: @SemyonBurov you mean [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eaeac2b9008a97d9) ?

Comment: Yes, like this. It works, thank you)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Answers belong as answers. What is so hard to understand about this that you *always* post answers in comments?

Comment: The question is not marked as solved this way.. or OP, would you mark an existing answer or  write your solution as answer and that it solved it?

Comment: I'm posted @Piotr Skotnucki solution, but I cant mark it as answer 2 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From commentary of @PiotrSkotnicki

```
template <template <typename...> class Base, typename Derived>
struct is_base_of_template
{
    using U = typename std::remove_cv<Derived>::type;

    template <typename... Args>
    static std::true_type test(Base<Args...>*);

    static std::false_type test(void*);

    using type = decltype(test(std::declval<U*>()));
};

template <template <typename...> class Base, typename Derived>
using is_base_of_template_t = typename is_base_of_template<Base, Derived>::type;
```

This solution works fine, [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d32557c6517af7f3).

Answer (score 3):

You may create a trait for that, something like:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <template <typename > class C>
    struct is_base_of_any_helper
    {
        template <typename T>
        std::true_type operator ()(const C<T>*) const;

        std::false_type operator() (...) const;

    };

}

template <template <typename > class C , typename T>
using is_base_of_any =
    decltype(detail::is_base_of_any_helper<C>{}(std::declval<const T*>()));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1f4ee13f47779ed)

Note that it will fail with some edge cases such as:

- multiple bases `C<Tx>`
- private inheritance of `C<T>`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use static_assert.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert

So for example, if you have a base class

```
template< typename T >
class Base<T> {};
```

and the derived one

```
template< typename T >
class Derived : public Base<T> {};
```

with your use case

```
template< typename Tsource, typename Tstorage > 
class Test
{
    std::static_assert( std::is_base_of< base<T>, TStorage >::value );
}
```

It is not possible to get T without adding it as a template parameter.

But with a simple trick, you get it. You have to add a typedef to Derived:

```
template< typename T >
class Derived : public Base<T> 
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
};
```

And you can use it inside of the static assertion.

```
template< typename Tsource, typename Tstorage > 
class Test
{
    std::static_assert( std::is_base_of< base<TStorage::value_type>, TStorage >::value );
}
```

Since Tstorage is a Derived, it has the value_type field.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Also, this doesn't really answer his question.

Comment: The OP is asking how to use that thing to assert another thing.

Comment: I edited the answer and provided example code for the OPs use case as far as I understood him correctly. I also added the use case I think he needs it for.